# Office add-in -- how to provide functionality on some platforms but not others?

Tags: office-js, word-addins

I have a Word add-in with feature A and feature B.  These are implemented in two different task panes.

Feature A works on all Word versions that I care about.

Feature B works on Word 2016 but not Word 2013.  If a Word 2013 user tries to access this feature, I present a message in the task pane that says this feature is not supported in this version of Word.

Microsoft rejected my add-in with the message "Your offer is not working in Office 2013".

Does this mean that I have to either:

- stop supporting Word 2013 entirely, or
- remove feature B?

That seems kind of dumb.  Why shouldn't I be able to provide all features to Word 2016 users and a subset of features for Word 2013 users.

Is there another solution that I am missing?

Comment: Are you using [Requirement Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/office-versions-and-requirement-sets?view=common-js) and [isSetSupported](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.requirementsetsupport?view=common-js#issetsupported-name--minversion-) to present the message?

Comment: @RickKirkham, yes, that is how I do it.

Comment: @RickKirkham, the question is about Microsoft policies rather than how to accomplish it from a software perspective.

Comment: I'll see if I can get some answers internally in Microsoft. I needed to confirm that you're using Req Sets because I know that's the first question that I'd be asked. ;-)

Comment: @RickKirkham, thanks!  All your assistance here is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why the 2 taskpanes? if you use isSetSupported you should be able to handle both cases. Upon initialization of the add-in you should check the requirement you need and then render the appropiate UI for that host.

Comment: @JuanBalmori, I have two task panes because they are two different features.  Button A on the ribbon opens task pane A to implement feature A.  Button B on the ribbon opens task pane B to implement feature B.  From a UX perspective, it doesn't make sense to implement these two features in the same task pane.

Comment: sorry I misunderstood your scenario. I thought you had a task pane just for 2013 and another one for 2016+.  Also it sounds like you are doing the right thing. Can you please send me an emai (juanbl@microsoft.com) i think we need to involve our validation team to help you go through this. thanks!

Comment: @JuanBalmori, thanks Juan, I've sent you an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the assistance of the Microsoft folks who posted in the comments, I was able to get Microsoft to approve the implementation described in my question.